# Pycuda messing up numpy matrix transpose

Tags: numpy, pycuda

Why does the transposed matrix look differently, when converted to a `pycuda.gpuarray`?

Can you reproduce this? What could cause this? Am I using the wrong approach?

**Example code**

```
from pycuda import gpuarray
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy

data = numpy.random.randn(2,4).astype(numpy.float32)
data_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(data.T)
print "data\n",data
print "data_gpu.get()\n",data_gpu.get()
print "data.T\n",data.T
```

**Output**

```
data
[[ 0.70442784  0.08845157 -0.84840715 -1.81618035]
 [ 0.55292499  0.54911566  0.54672164  0.05098847]]
data_gpu.get()
[[ 0.70442784  0.08845157]
 [-0.84840715 -1.81618035]
 [ 0.55292499  0.54911566]
 [ 0.54672164  0.05098847]]
data.T
[[ 0.70442784  0.55292499]
 [ 0.08845157  0.54911566]
 [-0.84840715  0.54672164]
 [-1.81618035  0.05098847]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic reason is that numpy transpose only creates a view, which has no effect on the underlying array storage, and it is that storage which PyCUDA directly accesses when a copy is performed to device memory. The solution is to use the `copy` method when doing the transpose, which will create an array with data in the transposed order in host memory, then copy that to the device:

```
data_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(data.T.copy())
```

Answer (score 6):

In numpy, `data.T` doesn't do anything to the underlying 1D array. It simply manipulates the strides to obtain the transpose. This makes it a constant-time and constant-memory operation.

It would appear that `pycuda.to_gpu()` isn't respecting the strides and is simply copying the underlying 1D array. This would produce the exact behaviour you're observing.

In my view there is nothing wrong with your code. Rather, I would consider this a bug in `pycuda`.

I've googled around, and have found [a thread that discusses this issue in detail](http://pycuda.2962900.n2.nabble.com/PyCUDA-gpuarray-to-gpu-strange-behavior-td6277252.html).

As a workaround, you could try passing `numpy.ascontiguousarray(data.T)` to `gpuarray.to_gpu()`. This will, of course, create a second copy of the data in the host RAM.

Comment: That is, indeed, how the `gpuarray` class works. Views and strided access for underlying data is not yet supported.

Comment: Hi aix, thanks for you detailed explanation (I upvoted you), but I've chosen talonmies' because that was the code I ended up using. cheers